# Name for an intermediate notion between huge and 2-huge

Tags: set-theory, terminology, large-cardinals

I am employing a large cardinal notion that has been used explicitly before, and I am wondering if someone has given it a good succinct name.

A cardinal $\kappa$ is huge if there is an elementary $j : V \to M$ with $M^{j(\kappa)} \subseteq M$.  $\kappa$ is 2-huge if the same but $M^{j^2(\kappa)} \subseteq M$.  There are provably intermediate notions where one just asserts for some particular cardinal $\lambda \in  (j(\kappa), j^2(\kappa))$, $M^\lambda \subseteq M$.  This has a characterization in terms of the existence of a normal ultrafilter concentrating $\{ x \subseteq \lambda \mathrel: \text{$\lvert x\rvert < j(\kappa)$ and $\operatorname{ot}(x \cap j(\kappa)) = \kappa$} \}$.

Did anyone name these cardinals?

Comment: Some suggestions (in case no one named these cardinals before): colossal cardinal, vast cardinal, yonder cardinal, 1.5-huge cardinal, and I can continue perhaps indefinitely.

Comment: Oy vey.  Well at least I want something that talks about $\lambda$, similar to "$\lambda$-supercompact."

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/1307.7387 might have a term for this cardinal.

Comment: I suggest $]1,2[$-huge because it states in a clear and short form what you want.

Comment: Actually I like it.  $\lambda$-sesquihuge.  Your comment was good, phantom commenter.

Comment: It looks kinda similar to the high jump cardinals in the paper I linked. Although I haven't sat down to contemplate the exact definition there.

Comment: $\lambda$-sesquihuge is interesting, but inevitably someone will want to look at similar things between $n$- and $(n+1)$-huge cardinals and I don't think our Latin forefathers gave us enough prefixes for all of these.

Comment: I like the fanciful names. But meanwhile, there is a notion "tall with closure $\lambda$", and in analogy with that, you could say that $\kappa$ is 1-huge with closure $\lambda$. For example, $n$-huge with closure $\lambda$ would mean $j:V\to M$ is $n$-huge and also $M^\lambda\subset M$. So the interesting case arises when $j^n(\kappa)<\lambda$.

Comment: If $\kappa<\lambda$, then in my paper on tall cardinals, I proved that $\kappa$ is tall with closure $\lambda$ just in case $\kappa$ is tall and also $\kappa$ is $\lambda$-supercompact. That is, the unified property is simply equivalent to the conjunction of the two separate properties. I couldn't make this work for your property (that is, having $\kappa$ be $\lambda$-supercompact and also huge with target below $\lambda$), but do you know that this doesn't work?

Comment: Looks like it doesn't work by strength considerations.  Suppose $\kappa$ is $\delta$-huge with closure $\lambda$, and $2^\delta<\lambda$.  Then some reflection arguments show that for stationary many $\alpha < \kappa$, $V_\kappa \models \alpha$ is supercompact and huge.

Comment: In Magidor and Shelah's paper, "The tree property at successors of singular cardinals," a cardinal $\kappa$ is called $\tau$-huge if there is an elementary embedding $j:V \rightarrow M$ with critical point $\kappa$ such that $\kappa < \tau < j(\kappa) < j(\tau)$ and $M^{j(\tau)} \subseteq M$.

Comment: @ChrisLambie-Hanson, this answers the question but it looks like there is also some inconsistency in terminology.  Woodin says "$\kappa_0$ is $\kappa_1$-huge'' to mean there is a huge embedding $j$ with critical point $\kappa_0$ and $j(\kappa_0) = \kappa_1$.  I think Joel's terminology sounds the most clear and robust: "crit = x, target = y, closure = z..."

Answer (score 1):

If there is a $\mu$ such that $j(\mu)=\lambda$, your property is called 2-fold $\mu$-supercompact ([Sato 2007 - Double helix in large large cardinals and iteration of elementary embeddings](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.apal.2007.02.003)) or $\mu$-hyperhuge ([Usuba 2017 - The downward directed grounds hypothesis and very large cardinals](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.05132)).